# Datatable button expand/collapse row JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using jQuery Datatable and I want to add a button for expand/collapse all row of my table. But I have an issue for the expand when I have row already expanded, and I click on the Button expandALL the row that I expand first is collapsed now and the other expand .. Or if I do the inverse he will be expanded and the other collapse .. 
How can I do for expand all row even I have already one expand (same case with the collapse)

```
    function init() {
      Docu.table = $('.js-table-doc').DataTable(dataTableSettngs());
      $('#btn-show-all-doc').on('click', expandCollapseAll);
    }

function dataTableSettings() {
            return {
                responsive: {
                    details: {
                      type: 'column'
                    }
                },
                serverSide: true,
                searching: false,
                columnDefs: [
                             {targets: [0, 8], orderable: false}}
                  ], 
                 columns: [{data: 'id'},
                          {data: 'name'}]
          }

function expandCollapseAll() {
        Document.table.rows(':not(.parent)').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click').length ||
        Document.table.rows('.parent').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click')

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has only open action. To close

```
table.rows('.parent').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click')
```

https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-expand-collapse-all-child-rows/#responsive

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  responsive: {
    details: {
      type: 'column'
    }
  },
  columnDefs: [{
    className: 'control',
    orderable: false,
    targets: 0
  }],
  order: [1, 'asc']
});

$('#btn-show-all-doc').on('click', expandCollapseAll);

function expandCollapseAll() {
  table.rows('.parent').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click').length || 
  table.rows(':not(.parent)').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click')
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-show-all-doc">Expand / Collapse</button>

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="all">First name</th>
      <th class="all">Last name</th>
      <th class="all">Position</th>
      <th class="all">Office</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="none">Start date</th>
      <th class="none">Salary</th>
      <th class="none">Extn.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>1562</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
      <td>6224</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
      <td>5407</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Brielle</td>
      <td>Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
      <td>4804</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, It is worked for the expand .. But when the rows is expanded and I click again on the button, the rows are not collapsed.. I edit the code on the topic

Comment: It collapses when all rows are expanded. Do you want to collapse rows if at least one expanded?

Comment: Yes I want this .. For my case now, when all rows are expanded I can not collpase

Comment: @user1814879 After reading multiple times Still not clear what you want? Give complete cases list

Comment: I updated my code, but it is very strange ..same issue.. If I expand one row and I click on expand/collapse button, the other row is expanded and the first expanded is collape (Ex : 10rows by default, I expand 1 row , I click on the button the 9rows are expanded and this one row is collapsed )

Comment: It's working a bit different here. Is the demo here working correctly?

Comment: Yes your demo worked well, may be it is somewhere in my code that I missed something but I dont know what . I put the same code that you sent me

Comment: I think I found my issue, but how to resolve I dont know .. when I do a console.log for checink the number of rows collapsed it is already 0 even if all rows are collapsed . `console.log('Nb : ', Document.table.rows('.parent').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click').length);` ..

Comment: Is `Docu.table` and `Document.table` are same?

Comment: Yes I do mistake ..it is Document.. But now I resolve it but it is not very mice but is work .. what I do is to create two Buttons (Expand and Collapse).. And when I click on button Expland I Collapse before all row and after Expand like this :  `function expandAll() {
 collapseAll();
 var already = false;
 Document.table.rows().every(function(){
 if(!this.child.isShown() && already == false){
      already = true;
  Document.table.rows(':not(.parent)').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click'); }
   });
  }`

Comment: This answer was a lifesaver! Thanks. Is there anyway the 2 columns that expand in the rows can be displayed side by side? Like in your example it would be 3 equal columns next to each other. Maybe some kinda of "float: right"?

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible by click on the same row. Only one row expands at time and other gets collapsed.

```js
var form_table = $('#forms').DataTable({
  paging: true,
  responsive:true
});


$('#forms').on('click', 'tr td.dtr-control', function(event) {
  // Collapse row details
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var row = form_table.row( tr );
  if (row.child.isShown()) {
    // This row is already open - close it
    row.child.hide();
  }
  form_table.rows().every(function() {
    if (this.child.isShown()) {
      // Collapse row details
      this.child.hide();
      $(this.node()).removeClass('parent');
    }
  })
  if (row.child.hide()) {
    // Open this row
    row.child.show();
  }
});
```